# How get matrix of p-values for multiple Stuart-Maxwell test in R? Ask

Tags: r, testing, matrix, header, multiple-columns

I have a data set including 1o questions (Q1-Q10). I would like to extract P-values of pairwise Stuart-Maxwell tests and print them in a matrix with headers of column names in a way I can detect which P-value refers to which pairwise comparison. I have received help from an expert how to run the test and extract the results and I have tried to make the matrix with headers but I fail. I appreciate if someone can modify my code below.

```
data <- data.frame(Q1=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q2=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q3=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q4=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q5=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q6=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q7=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q8=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q9=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
               Q10=sample(1:5, 20,replace=T) )  #fake data
Labels<- names(data)
# Matrix to store the result
enter code here
groups <- unique( Labels )
result <- matrix(NA, nc=length(groups), nr=length(groups))
colnames(result) <- rownames(result) <- groups
# Loop
for( g1 in groups ) {
for( g2 in groups ) {
result[ g1, g2 ] <- 
      sapply(labels <-combn(groups, 2, simplify = FALSE), function(i) {


    require(irr)

    xtab <- table(data[,i[1]], data[,i[2]])
    test <- try(stuart.maxwell.mh(xtab))
    ifelse(class(test) == "try-error", NA, test$p)
})



}

}

result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close. You just mixed up two methods. You should either use `sapply` with `combn` or the double `for-loop`s. In your case and based on the output you want `for-loop`s seem easier:

```
require(irr)
data <- data.frame(Q1=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q2=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q3=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q4=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q5=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q6=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q7=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q8=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q9=sample(1:5, 20, replace=T),
                   Q10=sample(1:5, 20,replace=T) )  #fake data

# Loop
labels<- names(data)
groups <- unique(labels)
result <- matrix(NA, nc=length(groups), nr=length(groups))
colnames(result) <- labels
rownames(result) <- labels

for( g1 in groups ) {
 for( g2 in groups ) {

  xtab <- table(data[,g1], data[,g2])
  test <- try(stuart.maxwell.mh(xtab), silent = TRUE)
  pval <- ifelse(class(test) == "try-error", NA, test$p)
  result[g1, g2] <- pval

 }
}
```

Output:

```
> result
           Q1         Q2         Q3        Q4        Q5        Q6         Q7         Q8
Q1         NA 0.05881900 0.26298902        NA 0.7790233 0.5177394 0.73754470 0.30610257
Q2  0.0588190         NA 0.58635825        NA 0.1005838 0.3678794 0.17078180 0.05626191
Q3  0.2629890 0.58635825         NA 0.3173105 0.3916252 0.2541583 0.09984288 0.07472086
Q4  0.3173105 0.36787944         NA        NA        NA        NA         NA         NA
Q5  0.7790233 0.10058381 0.39162518 0.2231302        NA 0.3114032 0.14247485 0.17708783
Q6  0.5177394 0.36787944 0.25415830        NA 0.3114032        NA 0.21636999 1.00000000
Q7  0.7375447 0.17078180 0.09984288        NA 0.1424749 0.2163700         NA 0.41099506
Q8  0.3061026 0.05626191 0.07472086 0.3173105 0.1770878 1.0000000 0.41099506         NA
Q9  0.6712714 0.53408090 0.16832466 0.3173105 0.2110881 0.2635971 0.28933534 0.31414685
Q10 0.2220359 0.38332585 0.05941603 1.0000000 0.1652989 0.2578472 0.23889094 0.08826479

#the output is truncated
```